# SQL returning 'Subquery returned more than 1 value' error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Okay so this is my bit of code thats giving me this error:

```
Select orderid, requireddate,
    (   Select DATEDIFF(dd,requireddate,shippeddate)
        from sales.Orders 
        where shippeddate > requireddate
    ) as 'DaysLate'
from sales.Orders
```

and I get the "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression." error.

I'm not quite sure how to fix it, as when I click on the error message it highlights the     `Select orderid, requireddate` bit.

Is there something wrong that I'm not catching?

Comment: your subquery returned multiple records, you need to modify your query. is there more condition to add in the where clause?

Answer (score 1):

try this below sql

```
select 
    orderId, requiredDate
    , case 
        when shippeddate > requireddate then DATEDIFF(dd,requireddate,shippeddate)
        else
            0
      end as 'DaysLate'
from sales.Orders
```

the case..when statement can replace the subquery

Answer (score 0):

```
Select orderid, requireddate,
       DATEDIFF(dd,requireddate,shippeddate)  as 'DaysLate'
from sales.Orders
where shippeddate > requireddate
```

Your subquery returns multiple rows but for outer query each column can have only one value so this gives the error as being shown

Comment: Sorry, I have to use a subquery for this.

Comment: I need to learn how to use subqueries. Yes its for an assignment, but I am actually very stuck on this.

Comment: well than error will be thrown unless the subquery is guaranteed to return only one result per outer query row ... you can force this by using TOP 1 clause as shown in other posted answers but this will give same value for of 'DaysLate' for all outer query rows which I think you don't want

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that a sub query used in this way returns no more than 1 value.

So at least use `TOP 1`. Something like

```
Select orderid, requireddate,
    (   Select TOP 1 DATEDIFF(dd,requireddate,shippeddate)
        from sales.Orders 
        where shippeddate > requireddate
    ) as 'DaysLate'
from sales.Orders
```

You might want to include an `ORDER BY` here too, if required.

Ultimately, you need to figure out what the value is you are looking for, and ensure that this single value is returned.

You might also want to take into account the actual `orderid`s. Something like

```
Select orderid, requireddate,
    (   Select TOP 1 DATEDIFF(dd,requireddate,shippeddate)
        from sales.Orders oo
        where shippeddate > requireddate
        and oo.orderid = o.orderid
    ) as 'DaysLate'
from sales.Orders o
```

Comment: The DateDiff returns a different result for each record, and using Top 1 just returns the same result for each record and I can't have that.

Answer (score 0):

Imho you are missing o1.orderid = o2.orderid in your sql query.
This is original way:

```
Select o1.orderid, o1.requireddate,
    (   Select DATEDIFF(dd,o2.requireddate,o2.shippeddate)
        from sales.Orders o2
        where o2.shippeddate > o2.requireddate and o1.orderid = o2.orderid
    ) as 'DaysLate'
from sales.Orders o1
```

And then rewritten a bit:

```
Select o1.orderid, o1.requireddate, DL.DaysLate
from sales.Orders o1
    join (   Select o2.orderid, DATEDIFF(dd,o2.requireddate,o2.shippeddate) as DaysLate 
        from sales.Orders o2
        where o2.shippeddate > o2.requireddate
    ) as DL on dl.orderid = o1.orderid
```

You havent described what is the business meaning of the data you want to retrieve, so use join/left join there.